# Designing high bandwidth current sensors for inductor current sensing

Tags: analog, adc, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, current-sensing

I am designing a high-frequency current sensor, suitable for sensing +/- 20 Amps at frequencies of 200kHz. This is being used in average current mode control application in an isolated forward converter I'm designing. Do you have any suggestions?

I need to just get you suggestion on the analog front end amplifier that can take a +/- 50 mV signal from a shunt resistor and amplify it to +/- 10 v while preserving the bandwidth of 250 kHz or more. Do you have any suggestions in this regard? I considered an INA828 analog front end instrumentation amplifier at a gain of 200 for achieving this, but, under such circumstances, the bandwidth is less than 260 kHz (the datasheet gives 260kHz bandwidth at a gain of 100, so I'm guessing it is less than 200kHz at 200 gain)

I also found this OPAx354 250-MHz, Rail-to-Rail I/O, CMOS Operational Amplifiers that can have a gain-bandwidth product of 100 MHz, so at a gain of 200 I get a bandwidth of 500kHz., so are these better choices? I have never designed current sensors before. Am I thinking about these in the right way?

Comment: What is the waveform and what important characteristics of the waveform are you concerned with?

Comment: @Andyaka I am capturing triangular waveforms with a dc offset and I especially need to capture the average value of this waveform  (average dc current). I need proper bandwidth information above 250 kHz and I need to sense the signal within the amplitude specs

Comment: Then use an RC filter and amplify the average value.